# Execute stored procedure within Openrowset to place in temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have spent an entire day on trying to figure this out and am ready for some help.

I am trying to get the following code to work. (user and pass are left out for obvious reasons)
I am running query from SSMS and am looking to take the contents of a store procedure and place it in a temp table.  Can you please fix my query so that it works.  :)

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SQL01\SQL2008R2;Database=ExtData;
Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx',
     'EXEC sp_MonthlyInventoryStock')
```

This is the error I get:

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>   Configuration option 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Authentication failed.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: sorry... A typo... it is server.  Just changed it.  Same error.

Comment: If I use the IP address instead of the server name, I get the same error.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you try to connect to remote server using SSMS?

Comment: This may sound odd, but I can replicate only when my connection string  spans multiple lines (like yours).  If I put `Uid=...` on the same line as the rest of the connection string, then I don't get the error.

Comment: This works? SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=SQL01\SQL2008R2; UID=MyUser; PWD=MyPassword', 'SELECT 1')

Comment: @SQLhint - yes i can connect using SSMS

Comment: @Mr.Reband - Thank you.  It looks like that fixed the problem.  That is wierd.  The connection string must be all on one line for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mr. Reband answered the question.  It looks like the connection string must be all on the same line.

You also need to include 'SET FMTONLY OFF; and have the S.P. set NOCOUNT to ON.

Final answer(the connection string is all on one line):

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
                ,'Server=SQL01\SQL2008R2;Database=ExtData;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx'
                ,'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;EXEC sp_MonthlyInventoryStock')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is caused by a extra space in connection string.

(local);**Space**TRUSTED

not working:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=(local); TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
  ,'exec master.dbo.sp_who')
```

working one

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
 ,'exec master.dbo.sp_who')
```